# Can I write a code only using static(class) methods?

Tags: java

So my question is based on my homework instruction.

The professor wouldn't answer instantly so here I am!

"Use static (class) methods to create and print 2-dimensional arrays of characters in different
patterns." 
That is the objective of the assignment.

That does mean I have to write the code only using `public class () iAmDumbSorry` methods?

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It means to use static methods, seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is *possible* to write java code that solely relies on static fields/methods.

But the point is: *static* has various implications, as it simply kills your ability to **override** methods. In other words: static-only means: no polymorphism. Which makes using an OOP language almost pointless.

Sometimes an education plan starts with "static only", assuming that this is easier for students to follow. And then the non-static things are excluded, and explained later on.

So your code would look like this:

```
class Foo {
  static int someInt;
  static void bar() { ... }
```

and

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(... {
    Foo.bar();
    if (Foo.someInt == ) ..
```

Long story short: take this unclear assignment as motivation to learn about the differences between static and non-static, and see what effects it has on your ability to express your thoughts in code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those classes are called utility classes. You can compare it to the [`java.util.Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) which consists only of static methods.